# Creating many random test database entries

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, unit-testing

I'm working on a simple time sheet webapp. I have created the following query (simplified - I actually have several mapped columns of a similar type to `project_id`) to generate test data:

```
INSERT INTO `entries` (`entry_id`, `user_id`, `project_id`, `date`, `comment`, `hours`)
VALUES
( null,
  0,
  (SELECT `project_id` FROM projects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
  CURRENT_DATE(),
  '# TEST DATA #',
  (SELECT ROUND((0.25 + RAND() * (24 - 0.24)), 2))
);
```

I'm currently running this query inside a PHP loop.

This code is currently adequate for my needs *now*, as I can iterate 50 loops in 0.3037 seconds. However, I fear that when it comes time to test large data sets (searching and report generation for `rows > 1 000 000`), I may run into problems creating them.

How can I optimize this algorithm? Should I consider using a stored procedure? Or should I just not worry about it, and run the loop to longer iterations, more times?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_test_entries`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `create_test_entries` (IN number INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT 'Creates `number` of random test entries in the timesheet'
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE i < number DO
        INSERT INTO `entries` (`entry_id`, `user_id`, `project_id`, `department_id`, `task_id`, `date`, `comment`, `hours`)
        VALUES
        ( null,
          0,
          (SELECT `project_id` FROM projects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
          CURRENT_DATE(),
          '# TEST DATA #',
          (SELECT ROUND((0.25 + RAND() * (24 - 0.24)), 2))
        );
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
```

Comment: Stored procedures? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

Comment: So, what's about your original question? Is this approach any faster? :-)

Comment: @loki2302 I've never run long queries like this before, so basically: is running this type of stored procedure a million times a bad idea, is there a more efficient way to do it, or anything else that jumps out?

Comment: Accessing database million times is always bad idea. If you need to have a million of entries, just make this SP generate you all these entries at once and then call it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like `(SELECT project_id FROM projects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)` stands for "get random but still valid project_id". You could probably just iterate over all of your projects (with no randomness) and for every project add a random number of records. I don't think it affects your intention but this will probably work faster.

Answer (score 0):

#### Performance

How does this query work?

> ```
> SELECT `project_id` FROM projects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
> ```

The database will assign a random number to every single record,
and then find the first.
So even though only one record gets selected,
all records get assigned a random value.
This could be expensive when you have a lot of records.

If it's not a problem to load all project ids to memory,
then it will be much more efficient.

#### Logic in code or database

Keeping logic in code is a lot easier to manage than keeping it in a stored procedure,
because you can easily add it to version control and track changes to it.
So I think stored procedures should be a last resort,
and only in performance-critical situations.

You could run a million INSERT queries fast if you stick all of them into a single string, and use the [multi_query API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.multi-query.html).
But even a simple loop might be good enough,
if you use prepared statements.

#### Suspicious code in the stored procedure

In the posted stored procedure,
the columns in the `INSERT` and in the `SELECT` sub-query don't match:
it looks like `CURRENT_DATE()` comes in the place of `department_id`.
I guess it was a copy-paste error in the question,
but I think it's worth pointing out anyway.

> ```
>     INSERT INTO `entries` (`entry_id`, `user_id`, `project_id`, `department_id`, `task_id`, `date`, `comment`, `hours`)
>     VALUES
>     ( null,
>       0,
>       (SELECT `project_id` FROM projects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
>       CURRENT_DATE(),
>       '# TEST DATA #',
>       (SELECT ROUND((0.25 + RAND() * (24 - 0.24)), 2))
>     );
> ```